# Authorization header not recognized by Yelp Fusion API

Tags: java, android, retrofit, yelp

I am passing an authorization header with my Retrofit GET requests as documented by the Yelp Fusion documentation, which is shown below:

Authorization: Bearer MY_API_KEY

I am adding a network interceptor in my onCreate() method as shown below:

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Request customization: add request headers
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer MY_API_KEY");
            Request request = requestBuilder.build();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    //Yelp Client init
    yelpRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://httpbin.org/")
            .client(okHttpBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    yelpClient = yelpRetrofit.create(YelpClient.class);
```

Here is my YelpClient class :

```
public interface YelpClient {
@GET("headers")
Call<YelpJSON> searchTest(); }
```

This is the response I get when sending the request:

> {"error": {"code": "TOKEN_MISSING", "description": "An access token must be supplied in order to use this endpoint."}}

I have successfully retrieved a response from the Yelp Fusion API with Postman and curl both using identical parameters and headers as my Retrofit request, so I can't blame Yelp. I have also attempted statically and dynamically setting the header with no success. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you add a logging interceptor and check if the auth header is added?
 see https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Comment: Also try reducing this to the smaller reproducible case. for example, switch yelp endpoint to https://httpbin.org/headers and look at the response. You'll see if the header is actually being sent over the wire.

Comment: What versions of retrofit and okhttp are you using?

Comment: @Devstr I tried switching yelp endpoint to https://httpbin.org/headers and the response has no Authorization field included in the header. I am using Retrofit 2.3.0 for my app

Comment: just did the logging interceptor that you suggested and there is no field being added for Authorization!!! The Request object contains the authorization header, but the Response object being returned does NOT have it.

Comment: I get the same error, using the Yelp sample code in PostMan as recoomended.  Tested at httpbn as devstr suggested (nice resource btw), and I get the error, "Could not get any response"